# CSS Flexbox/Grid - Wrap columns of wrapped items in multiple rows

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I have several items grouped by day, and I want to display them in columns, as it's the most readable way. Problem is, I have often too much items and columns overflow on the right. Is there a way to wrap columns dynamically to stay responsive ?

Here is the thing I want to do :

```
Day 1   - Item  - Item
- Item  - Item  Day 4
- Item  Day 3   - Item
- Item  - Item  - Item
- Item  - Item  Day 5
Day 2   - Item  - Item
- Item  - Item  - Item


- Item  -Item    ...
- Item  ...
Day 6
- Item
- Item
- Item
- Item
```

The only solution I have today is to count items and split them in rows of flex wrapped columns with JS, which is not beautiful. Is there a way to achieve this only with flexbox or grid ?

Here is an approximation of what I have :

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="day">Day 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="day">Day 2</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="day">Day 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    ...
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 150px;
}
```

(associate [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqgrdm04/1/))

Comment: You can use `flexbox` and `flex-wrap: wrap` property on the wrapper of your days container. But can you please provide some code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Is there a possibilety that you create a simple illustration of what you are trying to achieve? Do you want the 7 days next to eachother in columns with the items under it as rows? Or do you want all the items under eachother sorted by day and eventually take a new column if the length gets to long? A simple illustration could help explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `column-count` property. It does *not* wrap the "overflowing" `item` in `column 3` onto a new `row` in `column 1` like you seem you want it to behave, but rather increases the `height` of `container` and keep the flow of `items` intact.

I could argue this works even better in terms of readability, but I do not know your reason why you want the `container` to have a `max-height`, yet also want a new `container` *underneath* the first `container` if the first starts to overflow. That puzzles me. If you *need* to keep the `max-height`, the best option is using JS.

Example using `column-count` below. I've added an media query example to make it responsive, with a `column-count` of 1 on smaller screen sizes.

```css
.back {
  background: red;
  width: 210px;
}

.container {
  column-count: 3;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.container > * {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
  .container {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="day">Day 1</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="day">Day 2</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="day">Day 3</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="day">Day 4</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="day">Day 5</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="day">Day 6</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
      <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is one of my choices, and thanks to you I found `column-count: auto;` which allows to keep some responsivness.

My goal is to allow user to see the most recent items without to have to scroll, keeping scrolling for the farthest days.